# IBAction is not getting called for Button inside UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have created a view for custom callout with a button. This custom callout gets displayed on click of any annotation on Mapview. But nothing happens when I click the button inside the custom callout.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestView : UIView


@end

#import "TestView.h"

@implementation TestView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Test");
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    if(![view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,268,140);

        TestView *testview = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

        testview = [self loadNibNamed:@"TestView" ofClass:[TestView class]];


        [view addSubview:testview];
    }
}
```

The view is loaded using loadNibNamed method.

```
- (id)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName ofClass:(Class)objClass {
    if (nibName && objClass) {
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in objects ){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:objClass])
                return currentObject;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

[image]

I have checked the userInteractionEnabled property for View and Button and both are set to true.

Also mapped the showMessage with Touch Up Inside event of button.

any suggestion on how I go about identifying this problem?

Comment: A common error is simply not connecting the action correctly within IB.  Have you checked that?

Comment: Thanks I have checked that, included the screenshot of the same.

Comment: I just found the mistake,  [view addSubview:testview]; should be replaced with [mapView addSubview:testview]; Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following static method to get TestView

```
+ (TestView *)getNewTestView {
    TestView *view = nil;
    NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestView" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (NSObject *obj in xib) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[TestView class]]) {
            view = (TestView *)obj;
        }
    }
    return view;
```

}

And then, to get an instance of the object, use:

```
 TestView *testView = [TestView getNewTestView];
 [self.view addSubview:testView];
```

Comment: Adding to self.view actually solved the problem and also looks the correct way. So I have accepted this as the solution. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your MKAnnotationView has enough space to fill testView in.
If it's smaller than testView, the outer space would not respond to any actions.
You can set clipsToBounds to NO to check out the actual space.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
if(![view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    view.clipsToBounds = NO;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,268,140);

    TestView *testview = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

    testview = [self loadNibNamed:@"TestView" ofClass:[TestView class]];


    [view addSubview:testview];
}
```

}